# Location field complete values not showing up

Tags: theming

while searching for location, the location auto-complete drop down is not showing complete values. [image]

link is http://muslimdistricts.ikonami.com/

Comment: pls elaborate your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you are asking.
But having visited the site and clicked like in the example above it looks like the location pop up window has set dimensions and because of this the locations are getting cut off. Look into changing the pop up dimensions or reactions of that box....
Having just looked at it again you need to set the blocks overflow to not hidden. At the moment it is set to hidden so that the autocomplete is hidden when it overflows over the boxes border. To see it in action like the example below inspect the element in your browser and uncheck the overflow:hidden css.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. I hope you have a great day. Thanks very much.